# Optimizing Chi-square distance between two distribution

Tags: programming, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, code-review

I want to program the chi-square between two distribution Xu and Vu with length N. This function is defined as below:  Xu and Vu are real and  positive.

```
chiDistance[U_, V_] := Module[{vecs, vselect}, (
(*delete the {0,0} occurrence to avoid the division by zero*)
   vecs = Join[Transpose[{U}], Transpose[{V}], 2];
   vselect = Select[vecs, # != {0., 0.} &];
   (1/2) Total[(vselect[[All, 1]] - 
         vselect[[All, 2]])^2/(vselect[[All, 1]] + 
        vselect[[All, 2]])]

   )]
```

This function take

> 0.047625 when N=40000

When I replaced `Select[]` by `DeleteCases[]`, I got the same complexity.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether the intention is vectors with all positive entries. If not then potential pairs (a,-a) will also be  division by zero.

Here is another implementation of formula, removing zero denominators:

```
cd[u_, v_] := Module[{pos, us, vs},
  pos = Position[u + v, _?(# != 0 &)];
  us = Extract[u, pos];
  vs = Extract[v, pos];
  Total[(us - vs)^2/(us + vs)]/2]
```

or exploiting `SparseArray` properties:

```
cdsa[u_, v_] := Module[{pos, us, vs},
  pos = SparseArray[u + v]["NonzeroPositions"];
  us = Extract[u, pos];
  vs = Extract[v, pos];
  Total[(us - vs)^2/(us + vs)]/2]
```

Appears to confer only small advantage:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
BenchmarkPlot[{cdsa @@ # &, 
  chiDistance @@ # &}, {RandomInteger[{0, 10}, #], 
   RandomInteger[{0, 10}, #]} &, {100, 1000, 10000, 40000}, 
 "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: using `Total[N@(us - vs)^2/(us + vs)]/2` in the last line of `cdsa` seems to make it much faster (+1).

Comment: @kguler thank you, I should have tested on reals but done in haste...

Comment: @ubpdqn, I edited my question. the two vectors are real and positive. So, I think that the use of Total[N@(us - vs)^2/(us + vs)]/2 does not change the complexity.